# Does hard-boiling eggs in broth impact flavor?

Tags: eggs, flavor, boiling, broth, hard-boiled-eggs

I think the question says it all. I was looking at Marinated Soft Boiled Egg recipes for ramen and while trying them out I found it annoying to have a pot of boiling water for the eggs as well as a pot of simmering broth for the soup.

So would cooking CIFA Grade A Eggs in the broth impact the resulting flavor? I know eggs are slightly porous so I'm guessing some broth would get inside the egg. I'm also wondering (not too worried about it though) if it's a good idea to eat the broth afterwards since it might've absorbed the chemicals used to clean the eggshell ).

Comment: I am writing this as a comment, not an answer because it's not directly pertinent to Ramen. 

In my experience in eating Chinese cuisine (like in China, as I lived there) that has hard boiled eggs in them, I have found next to no difference in the taste of the broth/base and a nice flavour added to the egg (but not overwhelming). As for the chemicals, I wouldn't worry too much about them, I would think that the noodles and broth you would ingest otherwise would have more than the eggs could absorb.

Comment: @JCrosby Yeah I'm not too worried about the chemicals either, I think a swift rince like any vegs would be fine. Is this common in Chinese cuisine?

Comment: Yes, and no. I found it pretty common as a street food breakfast or lunch kind of thing. But at a sit down restaurant or even a homemade meal, not so much. I actually liked it and have adopted it into my cooking since moving back to Canada.

Comment: I do this at least twice a week for dinner.

Comment: @mroll So... does it impact flavor?

Comment: @Halhex I don’t think it does at all.

Comment: I would doubt it would impart any flavor into the egg. The shell is pretty tough, unless you crack the shell and then soak it, after it's been hard-boiled (like a Chinese tea egg).

Answer (score -2):

It does impact them, crockpot cooking in chicken broth. The lady that owns the hotel that I visit when I’m on business makes them all the time. Off the chain!